# Different output in a function and outside it

Tags: javascript, function

It is one of the beginner challenges for javascript, where you need to check whether the passed parameter(string of symbols, namely =, +, any letter) to a function, includes a random letter surrounded by +. If there is one, return true, else - false.

```
function simple(str) {
    let alph = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    let alphArray = alph.split('');
    for (let i = 0; i <= alphArray.length; i++) {
        if (str.includes(`+${alph[i]}+`)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

console.log(simple('+d+=3=+s+'));
```

It should return true, but I am certainly missing something, most likely it's the condition. 
Also, tried doing it without a function, with a predefined variable with the given symbols and it worked, but a in a sloppy way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `false` return statement outside of the loop, because this would end the loop immediately without checking the following possible true values and need to have the index smaller as the length of the string.

BTW, no need to use an array.

```js
function simple(str) {
    let alph = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    for (let i = 0; i < alph.length; i++) {
        if (str.includes(`+${alph[i]}+`)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(simple('+d+=3=+s+'));
```